# How does the mean value theorem with Hölder seminorms depend on dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces, parabolic-pde, mean-value-theorem

I am reading through Krylov's *Lectures on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Hölder Spaces*. In an attempt to prove the interpolation inequalities for parabolic PDEs, I've stepped back in the text to reference the relevant proofs in the Elliptic case. Starting with some definitions, we take

$$[u]_{\delta;\Omega} = \sup_{\substack{x,y \in \Omega\\ x\neq y}}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|}{|x-y|^{\delta}}$$
and
$$[u]_{k+\delta;\Omega} = \max_{|\alpha|=k}[D^{\alpha}u]_{\delta;\Omega}.$$

We take $\Omega$ to be an open convex cone, and want to show that (EDIT: taking $|\alpha| = j$)

$$\tag{1}|D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)| \leq N|x-y|[u]_{j+1;\Omega}$$.

My question is: how does $N$ (a constant dependent only on the dimension of the space $d$) appear here? By definition, we should have that

$$ \frac{|D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq [u]_{j+1;\Omega}$$

by the definition of the $j+1$ Hölder seminorm. Consequentially, should we not have that

$$\tag{2} |D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)| \leq |x-y|[u]_{j+1;\Omega} $$
independent of the dimension of the space? Krylov mentions that this is a consequence of the *mean value theorem*, but I have never seen a version of the MVT using Hölder seminorms as opposed to the value of the derivative along some line.

TL;DR, how does the MVT get you the existence of (1) as opposed to (2) given the context of the problem?

Comment: In statement (1) what is the range of $\alpha$ being considered?

Comment: In statement (1) we are specifically choosing $|\alpha| = j$, apologies for missing that detail.

Comment: I see no problem in setting $N=1$.

Comment: I agree that in this context we could set $N=1$, but my point of questioning here is that the result is cited as a consequence of the mean value theorem as opposed to just following from the definition of the $j+1$ Hölder seminorm. I am assuming that the N may depend on the MVT, but I cannot find a result that connects the MVT to the Holder seminorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of effort, it comes down to the way the $\delta$-Holder seminorm is defined for integral values. We note that

$$ [u]_{k+\delta} = \sup_{|\alpha|=k}[D^{\alpha}u]_{\delta}.$$
but if the value of $\delta$ is $1$, then it follows that $k+1$ is also an integer, and this is really just

$$[u]_{k+1} = \sup_{|\alpha|=k}[D^{\alpha}u]_{1}.$$
That is to say,
$$[u]_{k+1} = \sup_{|\alpha|=k}\frac{|D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)|}{|x-y|} = \sup_{|\alpha|=k+1}{|D^{\alpha}u(x)|}.$$

Note that by the mean value theorem (and $k+1$th differentiability of $u$), there is some point $\xi$ in the line $cx+(1-c)y$ for $c\in(0,1)$ for which
$$|D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)| = |\nabla D^{\alpha}u(\xi)\cdot(x-y)|.$$
However,
$$|\nabla D^{\alpha}u(\xi)| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\partial_{x_i}D^{\alpha}u(\xi)})^2 \leq \sqrt{n(\max_{i,\alpha}\partial_{x_i}D^{\alpha}u(\xi))^2} \leq \sqrt{n}\sup_{|\alpha|=k+1}|D^{\alpha}u(x)|.$$
Therefore,
$$|D^{\alpha}u(x)-D^{\alpha}u(y)| \leq \sqrt{n}|x-y|[u]_{k+1}.$$
The result above is, notably, dependent on $n$ (the dimension)! What truly remains left to be proven is why the thought process used above to get a bound independent of $n$ may be incorrect.